# What's wrong with my CS50 Vigenere code?

Tags: c, vigenere, cs50

I've been going round in circles with this now for a few hours. It manages the first word of the recommended test (Meet me at the park at eleven am) gets over the first spaces, gives a correct letter for m then prints several spaces before ending. Many thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int allstralpha();

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string keyw = argv[1];
    if(argc == 2 && allstralpha(keyw))
    {
        string plaint = GetString();
        int c = 0;
        int kl = strlen(keyw);
        int k = 0;
        int p = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0, n = strlen(plaint); i < n; i++)
        {      
            if(isalpha(plaint[i]))
            {        
                if(isupper(keyw[j]))
                {
                    k = keyw[(j % kl)] - 65;
                    if(isupper(plaint[i]))
                    {
                        p = plaint[i] -65;
                        c = ((k + p) % 26) + 65;
                        printf("%c", (char) c);                     
                    }   
                    else if(islower(plaint[i]))
                    {
                        p = plaint[i] -97;
                        c = ((k + p) % 26) + 97;
                        printf("%c", (char) c);
                    }
                }
                else if(islower(keyw[j]))
                {   
                    k = keyw[(j % kl)] - 97;
                    if(isupper(plaint[i]))
                    {  
                        p = plaint[i] - 65;                                  
                        c = ((k + p) % 26) + 65;             
                        printf("%c", (char) c);

                    }
                    else if(islower(plaint[i]))
                    {
                        p = plaint[i] - 97; 
                        c = ((k + p) % 26) + 97;
                        printf("%c", (char) c);
                    }   
                }
                j++;    
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", (char) plaint[i]);
            }
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Sorry that is not a vaild parameter\n");
        return 1;
    }  
}
int allstralpha(string s)
{   
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(!isalpha(s[i]))
        {
        return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1; 
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on the input and what the expected output should be

Comment: now, without looking too much into your code, let me ask you: are you providing the argument to the program enclosing the phrase between quotes? Please show how you call it from the command line.

Comment: Meet me at the park at eleven am
Negh zf av huf pcfx bt gzrwep oz

Comment: The english up to am should be encrypted as what follows. Sorry on my iphone now! I'm not using quotes if I understand you correctly for the arguments.

Comment: Check all your `keyw` accesses. There's a couple of places where you forgot to do `(j % kl)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int allstralpha();
int allstralpha(string s)
{   
...
}
```

Your function definition and declaration don't match. You should declare `int allstralpha(string s);`

In first line of main:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string keyw = argv[1];
    ...
}
```

First you should check `if (argc > 1)` before accessing `argv[1]`

For the actual code itself, you provide the plain text, but I can't see the keyword.

I use these values from [wikipedia, vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) for testing:

```
Plaintext:  ATTACKATDAWN
Key:        LEMONLEMONLE
Ciphertext: LXFOPVEFRNHR
```

Minimum code to finish this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const char *str = "Meet me at the park at eleven am";
    const char *key = "bacon";

    int keylen = strlen(key);
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int c = str[i];
        if (isalnum(c))
        {
            //int k = function of key and `j`...
            //offset k...
            if (islower(c))
            {
                c = (c - 'a' + k) % 26 + 'a';
            }
            else
            {
                c = (c - 'A' + k) % 26 + 'A';
            }
            j++;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer. The rest of is homework, you can finish that yourself.